# react/datastax/firebase app, submit button works only on local machine but not working on iphone or other macbooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, firebase-hosting, datastax-astra

I have a react app that sends input data to astradb and hosted on firebase domains, i'm using a rest api, the post method works on localhost:3000 and the firebase domain on my computer/network but when i try to submit my form on an iphone or another macbook, the submit button does not work

Ive tried to see it there are any permission problems with datastax/astradb or firebase and i cannot seem to find a good answer.

Ive tried on android phones also, still no response from the submit button

Since i cannot inspect the page on a phone with chrome, i really cant see the errors coming back on the console or network, can anyone please help me

This is my ContactForm.js

```
import { Checkbox, useCheckboxState } from "pretty-checkbox-react"
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import  { useNavigate  } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser"



const ContactForm = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [permission, setPermission] = useState(null)
    // const form = useRef()
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        datetime: new Date().toISOString(),
        fName: "",
        lName: "",
        email: "",
        zipCode: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        services: [],
    })

    const serviceData = [
        "Business Development",
        "Brand Creation",
        "Logo Design",
        "Digital Marketing/Ads",
        "Video/Photography",
        "Social Media/Content",
        "Web Development",
    ]



    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        //dont refresh
        e.preventDefault()

        //atra db
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/customers", {
            formData,
        })
        const success = response.status === 200
        if (success) {
            console.log("post was successful")
            navigate("/exitpage")
        }


        //clear fromData
        setFormData({
            datetime: "",
            fName: "",
            lName: "",
            email: "",
            zipCode: "",
            PhoneNumber: "",
            services: [],
        })
        //clear checkboxes
        setPermission(false)
    }


  const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        const name = e.target.name

        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }))
    }

    console.log(formData)

    return (
        <div className="contact-form">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <form validate autocomplete="on" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="col">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={formData.fName}
                                placeholder="first name"
                                name="fName"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required={true}
                            />

                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={formData.lName}
                                placeholder="last name"
                                name="lName"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                value={formData.email}
                                placeholder="example@email.com"
                                name="email"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                value={formData.zipCode}
                                placeholder="e.g. 66801"
                                name="zipCode"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <input
                                type="tel"
                                value={formData.phoneNumber}
                                placeholder="e.g. 6203341100"
                                name="phoneNumber"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                <h1>Please Select Services:</h1>
                            </legend>

                            {serviceData.map((data) => (
                                <div className="col">
                                    <label>
                                        <Checkbox
                                            style={{}}
                                            color="success"
                                            className="service"
                                            animation="rotate"
                                            checked={permission}
                                            plain
                                            icon={<i className="mdi mdi-close" />}
                                            value={data}
                                            name="services"
                                            onChange={(e) => {
                                                if (!formData.services.includes(e.target.value)) {
                                                    setFormData({
                                                        ...formData,
                                                        services: formData.services.concat(e.target.value),
                                                    })
                                                } else {
                                                    setFormData({
                                                        ...formData,
                                                        services: formData.services.filter(
                                                            (item) => item != e.target.value
                                                        ),
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {data}
                                        </Checkbox>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </fieldset>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="col submit buy-btn"
                            onClick={handleSubmit}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContactForm
```

this is my server.js post method for the contact form

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")


require("dotenv").config()
const axios = require("axios")

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const url = process.env.URL
const token = process.env.ASTRA_DB_TOKEN

//create customer
app.post("/customers", async (req, res) => {
    const formData = req.body.formData

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accepts: "application/json",
            "X-Cassandra-Token": token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: formData,
    }

    try {
        const response = await axios(url, options)
        res.status(200).json(response.data)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        res.status(500).json({ message: e })
    }
})
```

also using node v16.1.0

Comment: `localhost` refers to the device running the browser. You need to use a production address or at least the external address for your workstation instead of `http://localhost:8000/customers`

Comment: so i changed to urls to be my production address and the axios get methods now dont get any data from (productionaddress)/customers